# Prevent google indexing templateurl html page and JSON url [Angularjs + ASP.NET]

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, seo, single-page-application

I am using AngularJS framework and google do index my partial html pages paths and JSON requests. However, my website have more than one page but google indexed only home page partial html and JSON paths.

This is how I config routes

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    // etc...

    $routeProvider.when("/info/duk/", {
        controller: "faqCtrl",
        templateUrl: "App/info/faq/faq.html"
    });
    $routeProvider.when("/", {
        controller: "homeCtrl",
        templateUrl: "App/item/home/home.html"
    });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

So, google index this url "domain.com/App/item/home/home.html" which I don't want to. Furthermore, it indexes json request url: "domain.com/api/HomeApi?currentPage=1&recordsPerPage=12&sort=-1&cat=akcijos".

This issue of not wanted indexing occurs only with the home page requests.

Please advice for me tips how to properly disallow this unwanted indexing. I have opinion to allow access to partial pages and JSON requests only via XHR but I believe it's not the correct solution + complicated.

Edit: still need help.

Comment: No, Lex, you miss understood. If I disallow this in robots.txt crawler won't be able to crawl the page at all. There is no such availability with robots.txt to allow XHR but disallow direct url browsing.

Comment: **I am using AngularJS framework and google do index my *partial html pages paths and JSON requests*.** IF I block partial page path in robots.txt it won't be access-able at all. But google needs to access this template only via XHR load not directly.